# Is there a more pythonic way to build an INSERT statement?

Tags: python, postgresql

Trying to build an SQL statement for `execute`.  This works but now sure how pythonic it might be:

```
user_fields = ("id", "name", "email", "password", "phone")

fields = [field for field in user_fields if field != "id"]  # The only field we don't want is "id"
percent_s = ["%s"] * len(fields)
fields = ",".join(fields)
percent_s = ",".join(percent_s)

sql = "INSERT INTO user_table (" + fields + ") VALUES (" + percent_s + ")"
cursor.execute(sql, row_data)
```

Comment: Before anyone reflexively screams "SQL injection", note that what's being concatenated is just a list of placeholders.

Comment: IMO this is a deficiency of the Python DB-API. It should specify a placeholder like `%P` or something, which inserts a number of comma-separated placeholders equal to the number of query parameters passed. A variant that lets you specify how many placeholders as a parameter would also be nice.

Comment: I like portions of both answers so far.  With regards to "%s" being visually confusing in the sense of one potentially thinking "Oh no! SQL Injection!" I like @rofls answer with the idea of using `{}` and `.format`.  In other words, I am currently seeing it mostly as a visual differentiator.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_table (" + fields + ") VALUES (" + percent_s + ")"
```

with

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_table ({}) VALUES ({})".format(fields,percent_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `user_fields` has a fixed order, `row_data` must have a corresponding order. You have to ensure this somewhere. Then the position of `id` is also fixed. Then you can use string formatting, which leads to:

```
user_fields = ("id", "name", "email", "password", "phone")

sql = "INSERT INTO user_table (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (','.join(user_fields[1:], ','.join(['%s'] * (len(user_fields) - 1))
cursor.execute(sql, row_data)
```